The Transformations of Positive Real Functions
A function $f(z)$ holomorphic on $\Re [z]>0$ is called Positive Real (PR) iff

whenever $\Im [z] =0$ we have $\Im [f(z)]=0$
whenever $\Re[z] \ge 0$ we have $\Re [f(z)] \ge 0$

The composition of two PR functions, say, $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, is another PR function, $f(g(z))$. For example, if $f(z)$ is PR then so is its reciprocal $1/f(z)$ because $1/z$ is PR.
The impedance $Z(s)$ and admittance $1/Y(s)$ of a passive $RLC$ circuit between any two its nodes is PR and rational in the Laplace transform variable, that is a ratio of two polynomials so that all its coefficients are real and positive, and all the residues on the imaginary axis are real and positive, and all its other singularities, roots and poles, have negative real parts.
There is a famous result by Brune and Cauer that any PR rational function can be represented by a network of $RLC$ components. In fact, the representation is not unique, there are specific procedures to synthesize ladder, or parallel, or series resonator circuits, etc., all having the same driving point impedance.
According to the law of composition if $Z(s)$ is PR and we replace the complex frequency $s$ with another one, say, $s=w(p)$ where $w(p)$ is PR in the variable $p$, then $Z(w(p))$ is PR in $p$. Physically this means that in an $RLC$ circuit whose impedance is $Z(s)$ we replace each inductor $L$ of impedance $sL$ by a network whose impedance is $w(p)L$, and replace each capacitor $C$ of admittance $sC$ with a network whose admittance is $w(p)C$. Since $w(p)$ is assumed to be PR both replacements are realizable in the appropriately scaled $RLC$ network. This replacement across the whole network involving all inductors and capacitors is what the composition of the two PR functions means.
But in fact if we just replace each inductor or capacitor with a $w_k^{\ell}(p)L_k$ or $w_k^c(p)C_k$, where $w_k^{\ell,c}$ and $k=1,2,..$ are the branch indices of the network, are possibly different PR functions we again get a new "composite" PR function that cannot just be written as the usual composition of functions.
My question is twofold:

what kind of function transformation is this more general "replacement" that keeps the PR property?
assuming one is given $Z(s)$; if one starts with all circuit elements being appropriately energized, does the resulting transient response determine the possible topology? If not completely determines it then to what extent restricts it?

